# How to save a spark dataframe as a text file without Rows in pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe "df" with the columns  ['name', 'age']
I saved the dataframe using `df.rdd.saveAsTextFile("..")` to save it as an rdd. I loaded the saved file and then collect() gives me the following result.

```
a = sc.textFile("\mee\sample")
a.collect()
Output:
    [u"Row(name=u'Alice', age=1)",
     u"Row(name=u'Alice', age=2)",
     u"Row(name=u'Joe', age=3)"]
```

This is not an rdd of Rows.

```
a.map(lambda g:g.age).collect()
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'age'
```

Is there any way to save the dataframe as a normal rdd without column names and Row keywords? 
I want to save the dataframe so that on loading the file and collect should give me as follows:

```
a.collect()   
[(Alice,1),(Alice,2),(Joe,3)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a normal `RDD[Row]`. Problem is you that when you `saveAsTextFile` and load with `textFile` what you get is a bunch of strings. If you want to save objects you should use some form of serialization. For example `pickleFile`:

```
from pyspark.sql import Row

df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
   [('Alice', 1), ('Alice', 2), ('Joe', 3)],
   ("name", "age")
)

df.rdd.map(tuple).saveAsPickleFile("foo")
sc.pickleFile("foo").collect()

## [('Joe', 3), ('Alice', 1), ('Alice', 2)]
```

Comment: Yeah but how would you load that pickle file back to a spark df ?

Comment: @bluerubez OP doesn't want `DataFrame` back. There better formats if you want to serialize DataFrame, although tuples can work as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do like this:

```
a.map(lambda x:(x[0],x[1])).collect()
```